# Execute js function (which is defined in a execute_script()) in another execute_script()

Tags: python, selenium

Consider:

```py
driver.execute_script("function main(){console.log('this is main');}")
driver.execute_script(f"return main()")
```

The second `execute_script()` will cause
`selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: main is not defined`
How can I fix this **without** merging the two `execute_script()`?

---

**Clarification**
I want to "save" the js function so that in the future I can call the function with `execute_script()`, without redefining it.
For example:

```py
driver.execute_script(open("js_functions.js").read())
# Do sth
driver.execute_script(f"return funcA()")
# Do sth
driver.execute_script(f"return funcB()")
# Do sth
driver.execute_script(f"return funcA()")
```

Currently, I have to do like this

```py
# Do sth
js_funcs = open("js_functions.js").read() + "\n"
driver.execute_script(js_funcs + "return funcA()")
# Do sth
driver.execute_script(js_funcs + "return funcB()")
# Do sth
driver.execute_script(js_funcs + "return funcA()")
```

Comment: What is your end goal? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
driver.execute_script("function main(){console.log('this is main');}")
```

To this:

```
driver.execute_script("window.main = () => console.log('this is main')")
```

Explanation: the function was in another function's scope.